# How to count URL domains in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex, url

I have a MySQL table with a column of well-formed URLs. I'd like to get a table of the unique domain names in the column, and the number of times each domain appears. Is there a MySQL query that can do this?

I thought of doing something like...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM log
GROUP BY url REGEXP "/* regexp here */"
```

...but this doesn't work as REGEXP returns 0 or 1 and not what was matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return count of a certain domain:

```
SELECT  SUM(url REGEXP '^http://example.com')
FROM    log
```

Unfortunalely, `MySQL` doesn't return the matched string on regexps.

If your log records always look like `http://example.com/*`, you can issue:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3), COUNT(*)
FROM    log
GROUP BY
        1
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if they're full formed urls, you could first `replace("http://", "")` and replace everything after the first occurence of a `/`

so

```
http://www.domain.com/page.aspx
```

would become

```
www.domain.com
```

I'm not sure of the MySQL syntax for Replace but in MSSQL it would be.

```
DECLARE @url nvarchar(50)
SET @url = 'http://www.domain.com/page.aspx'
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(@url, 'http://', ''), CharIndex('/', REPLACE(@url, 'http://', '')) - 1)
```

From this you could get a subtable of all domain names and then count/group them.

```
SELECT
    Count(*),
    DomainOnly
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        LEFT(REPLACE(urlColumn, 'http://', ''), CharIndex('/', REPLACE(urlColumn, 'http://', '')) - 1) as DomainOnly
    FROM 
        TABLE_OF_URLS
) as Domains
GROUP BY 
    DomainOnly
```

Answer (score 0):

If by domain you mean TLD (thus you'd want to count `www.example.com`, `corp.example.com`, `www.local.example.com`, and `example.com` as one domain), then the regexp would be:

```
 '[[:alnum:]-]+\.[[:alnum:]-]+/'
```

I'm assuming that this are well formed URL's, in form of `schema://host/[path]`